# Add 30 days to the date by not taking system date in account in Nsdate

Tags: macos, ios5, xcode4.2, nsdate

I want to add 30 days to folder created date and block the app after 30 days.
If they changes the system date den also my app should close after the count.

```
NSDateComponents *components;
NSString *path = @"/Users/Syed/Library/Swasstik/KITSMAW0051_SWASSTIK_DB.sqlite";
BOOL isFile = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:NO];
if (isFile) {
NSLog(@"File exists");
NSDictionary* fileAttribs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil];
NSDate *result = [fileAttribs fileCreationDate]; //or fileModificationDate
NSLog(@"%@",result);
  NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"%@", [date description]);

NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                    fromDate:result
                                                      toDate:date
                                                     options:0];

[gregorianCalendar release];
NSLog(@"%ld", [components day]);
```

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't see what your question is. If you get the creation date of a file you can just compare it with the time now.

Comment: @codingFriend1 I don want to compare with system date.As user can change the system date and use my app.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try to find the most recently modified file on the system (for example one from the user's Preferences folder as these are modified very frequently) and compare against that modification date. Even when the user turns back his system time, files modified before will keep their newer modification date.

That of course will not work if the user permanently keeps his system time in the past (like 1990) but it will prevent attempts to only turn back time to use your app. I think it is very unlikely that someone will keep his system time wrong permanently as this is really inconvenient.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this ???.Like adding 30 days count to the folder created date.

Comment: Why do want to add 30 days to the creation date? However this is of course possible using the `setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:` method of NSFileManager similar to how you read the attributes in your code above.

Comment: I want to block the app after 30 days so i wanted to like this.